# Form not sending through to Feenix MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>ShipOnline System</title>
</head>
<body>  
  <h1>ShipOnline System Request Page</h1>
    <form method="post" action="request.php">
        <fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Item Information:</legend>
        <p><label for="description">Description:</label> 
            <input type="text" name= "description" id="description" maxlength="100" size="20"  required="required"/></p>

        <p><label for="weight">Weight (kg):</label> 
          <select name="weight" id="weight" required="required">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>         
            <option value="weight">0-2</option>
            <option value="weight">3</option>
            <option value='weight'>4</option>
            <option value='weight'>5</option>
            <option value='weight'>6</option>
            <option value='weight'>7</option>
            <option value='weight'>8</option>
            <option value='weight'>9</option>
            <option value='weight'>10</option>
            <option value='weight'>11</option>
            <option value='weight'>12</option>
            <option value='weight'>13</option>
            <option value='weight'>14</option>
            <option value='weight'>15</option>
            <option value='weight'>16</option>
            <option value='weight'>17</option>
            <option value='weight'>18</option>
            <option value='weight'>19</option>
            <option value='weight'>20</option>
          </select></p>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Pick-up Information:</legend>
        <p><label for="pickupAddress">Street Address:</label> 
          <input type="text" name= "pickupAddress" id="pickupAddress" maxlength="40" size="30" required="required"/></p>

        <p><label for="pickupSuburb">Suburb:</label> 
          <input type="text" name= "pickupSuburb" id="pickupSuburb" maxlength="40" size="20" required="required"/></p>

        <p><label for="date">Preferred date:</label> 
          <select name="day" id="date" required="required">
            <option value="">Day</option>         
            <option value="day">1</option>
            <option value="day">2</option>
            <option value="day">3</option>
            <option value='day'>4</option>
            <option value='day'>5</option>
            <option value='day'>6</option>
            <option value='day'>7</option>
            <option value='day'>8</option>
            <option value='day'>9</option>
            <option value='day'>10</option>
            <option value='day'>11</option>
            <option value='day'>12</option>
            <option value='day'>13</option>
            <option value='day'>14</option>
            <option value='day'>15</option>
            <option value='day'>16</option>
            <option value='day'>17</option>
            <option value='day'>18</option>
            <option value='day'>19</option>
            <option value='day'>20</option>
            <option value='day'>21</option>
            <option value='day'>22</option>
            <option value='day'>23</option>
            <option value='day'>24</option>
            <option value='day'>25</option>
            <option value='day'>26</option>
            <option value='day'>27</option>
            <option value='day'>28</option>
            <option value='day'>29</option>
            <option value='day'>30</option>
            <option value='day'>31</option>
          </select>
          <select name="month" id="date" required="required">
            <option value="">Month</option> 
            <option value='month'>1</option>
            <option value='month'>2</option>
            <option value='month'>3</option>
            <option value='month'>4</option>
            <option value='month'>5</option>
            <option value='month'>6</option>
            <option value='month'>7</option>
            <option value='month'>8</option>
            <option value='month'>9</option>
            <option value='month'>10</option>
            <option value='month'>11</option>
            <option value='month'>12</option>
          </select>
          <select name="year" id="date" required="required">
            <option value="">Year</option> 
            <option value='year'>2018</option>
            <option value='year'>2019</option>
            <option value='year'>2020</option>
            <option value='year'>2021</option>
          </select></p>

        <p><label for="time">Prefered time:</label> 
          <select name="time" id="time" required="required">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>         
            <option value="time">7:30-8:30</option>
            <option value="time">8:30-9:30</option>
            <option value="time">9:30-10:30</option>
            <option value="time">10:30-11:30</option>
            <option value="time">11:30-12:30</option>
            <option value="time">12:30-13:30</option>
            <option value="time">13:30-14:30</option>
            <option value="time">14:30-15:30</option>
            <option value="time">15:30-16:30</option>
            <option value="time">16:30-17:30</option>
            <option value="time">17:30-18:30</option>
            <option value="time">18:30-19:30</option>
            <option value="time">19:30-20:30</option>
          </select></p>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Delivery Information:</legend>
        <p><label for="receiver">Receiver Name:</label> 
          <input type="text" name= "receiver" id="receiver" maxlength="40" size="20" pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" required="required"/></p>

        <p><label for="deliveryAddress">Street Address:</label> 
          <input type="text" name= "deliveryAddress" id="deliveryAddress" maxlength="40" size="30" required="required"/></p>

        <p><label for="deliverySuburb">Suburb:</label> 
          <input type="text" name= "deliverySuburb" id="deliverySuburb" maxlength="40" size="20" required="required"/></p>

        <p><label for="state">State:</label> 
          <select name="state" id="state" required="required">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>         
            <option value="state">VIC</option>
            <option value="state">NSW</option>
            <option value="state">QLD</option>
            <option value="state">NT</option>
            <option value="state">WA</option>
            <option value="state">SA</option>
            <option value="state">TAS</option>
            <option value="state">ACT</option>
          </select></p>
      </fieldset>
      <br/>
      <input type= "submit" value="Request"/>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <p><a href="shiponline.php#shiponline">Home</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  require_once ("settings.php"); //connection info
  $conn = @mysqli_connect($host,
    $user,
    $pwd,
    $sql_db
  );

  $requestID = trim($_POST["requestID"]);
  $customerID = trim($_POST["customerID"]);
  $requestDate = trim($_POST["requestDate"]);
  $description = trim($_POST["description"]);
  $weight = trim($_POST["weight"]);
  $pickupAddress = trim($_POST["pickupAddress"]);
  $pickupSuburb = trim($_POST["pickupSuburb"]);
  $date = trim($_POST["date"]);
  $time = trim($_POST["time"]);
  $receiver = trim($_POST["receiver"]);
  $deliveryAddress = trim($_POST["deliveryAddress"]);
  $deliverySuburb = trim($_POST["deliverySuburb"]);
  $state = trim($_POST["state"]);

  $sql_table="Request";
  $query = "insert into $sql_table (description, weight, pickupAddress, pickupSuburb, date, time, receiver, deliveryAddress, deliverySuburb, state) values ('$description', '$weight', '$pickupAddress', '$pickupSuburb', '$date', '$time', '$receiver', '$deliveryAddress', '$deliverySuburb', '$state')";
  //execute the query -we should really check to see if the batabase exists first.
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  //checks if the exeution was succcessful
  if (!$result) {
      echo "<p class=\"wrong\">Something is wrong with your request please go back and check your details</p>";
      // would not show in a production script
    } else {
      // display an operation successful message
      echo "<p class=\"ok\">Thank you! Your request number is requestID. The cost is <cost>. We will pick-up the item at $time on $date.</p>";
    } // if successful query operation
    // close the database connection
  mysqli_close($conn);
   // if successful database connection
?>
```

I have a similar PHP document to this one which works perfectly. I believe the that I keep getting the message "Something is wrong with your request please go back and check your details" because of the 'date', 'time' or the drop boxes which are 'weight' and 'state' but I tried removing them and nothing changed I kept getting that there was something wrong. I can't seem to figure out what is causing the form to not successfully send. Could someone please try and find the error?

Comment: [This code might be vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Again, what is it with all your duplicate option values?

Comment: @kerbholz didn't realize the option values had to be different. It hadn't affected anything before so I assumed it was like this. I will be fixing this thanks for pointing it out

Comment: You could use [mysqli_error()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see what error gets thrown. This is usually quite helpful.

Comment: @kerbholz how exactly do i use mysqli_error()?

Comment: it's a function, you call it when you think an error has occurred (e.g. if the query or connect functions return false (as per the PHP documentation for mysqli, which you might want to read in detail, if you haven't, because it's quite well explained there already, with code examples). Also by putting @ in front of mysqli_connect, you're suppressing any errors which might be occurring at that time.

Comment: Also in the meantime see http://bobby-tables.com/ for an explanation of why your code is quite hackable (SQL injection vulnerabilities) and some code samples of how to resolve that in PHP/mysqli by using parameterised queries. Again though, the PHP/mysqli documentation does also cover this too.